# Writing Migrations with Foreign Keys Using SequelizeJS

Tags: node.js, database-migration, sequelize.js

**The Background**

I'm building a project with [SequelizeJS](http://sequelizejs.com), a popular ORM for NodeJS.  When designing a schema, there appears to be two tactics:

1. Create model code and use the .sync() function to automatically generate tables for your models.
2. Create model code and write [manual migrations](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/migrations/) using [QueryInterface](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/query-interface.js) and [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug).

My understanding is that #1 is better for rapid prototyping, but that #2 is a best practice for projects that are expected to evolve over time and where production data needs to be able to survive migrations.

This question pertains to tactic #2.

**The Question(s)**

My tables have relationships which must be reflected through foreign keys.

- How do I create tables with foreign key relationships with one another through the Sequelize QueryInterface?
- What columns and helper tables are required by Sequelize? For example, it appears that specific columns such as createdAt or updatedAt are expected.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> How do I create tables with foreign key relationships with one another through the Sequelize QueryInterface?

The `.createTable()` method takes in a dictionary of columns.  You can see the list of valid attributes in the [documentation for `.define()`](https://sequelize.org/v7/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-define), specifically by looking at the `[attributes.column.*]` rows within the params table.

To create an attribute with a foreign key relationship, use the "references" field.

For example, the following would create a `users` table, and a `user_emails` table which references the users table:

```
queryInterface.createTable('users', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  }
}).then(function() {
  queryInterface.createTable('user_emails', {
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: { model: 'users', key: 'id' }
    }
  })
});
```

> What columns and helper tables are required by sequelize? For example, it appears that specific columns such as createdAt or updatedAt are expected.

It appears that a standard model will expect an `id`, `updatedAt`, and `createdAt` column for each table.

```
queryInterface.createTable('users', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  }
}
```

If you set [`paranoid` to `true`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#including-soft-deleted-records) on your model, you also need a `deletedAt` timestamp.

Comment: For people ending up here, this answer is fine but the syntax is now deprecated, use the following : _references: {
            model: 'users',
            key: 'id'
          }_

Comment: you should also remove _referencesKey: 'id'_ ;)

Comment: (herp derp, that's what I get for using StackOverflow on a holiday)

Comment: How do you define references to multiple entities? So if I wanted to have it so that the "users" table has a column that references multiple rows in "user_emails" (instead of the current example where the "user_emails" row references one row in "users").

Comment: @Vinay I may be misunderstanding, but the nature of a foreign key is that it has to reference a primary key (there can only be one row per primary key value by definition) -- which means the referenced table would only have ONE row that contains that value.  You could flip the relationship, so that user emails has the primary key, and users has the foreign key (so more than one user could point to the same email)

Comment: @slifty I see. Table architecture is not my strong suit. :-) I do remember from my database class that this is the case, so you're correct.

Comment: @slifty thanks for the detailed answer. It helped a lot.

Comment: First link is outdated.

Comment: when i remove the column in another migration (or the down migration), do i need to explicitly remove the reference, too?

Comment: @FreTimmerman I would ask that as a separate question!

Answer (score 20):

I want to offer another **more manual alternative** because when using manual migrations and queryInterface I ran across the following problem: I had 2 files in the migration folder like so

```
migrations/create-project.js
migrations/create-projectType.js
```

because `project` had column `projectTypeId` it referenced `projectType`, which wasnt created yet due to the order of the files and this was causing an error.

I solved it by adding a foreign key constraint after creating both tables. In my case I decided to write it inside `create-projectType.js`:

```
queryInterface.createTable('project_type', {
  // table attributes ...
})
.then(() => queryInterface.addConstraint('project', ['projectTypeId'], {
  type: 'FOREIGN KEY',
  name: 'FK_projectType_project', // useful if using queryInterface.removeConstraint
  references: {
    table: 'project_type',
    field: 'id',
  },
  onDelete: 'no action',
  onUpdate: 'no action',
}))
```

Comment: Nice! one note -- you may want to consider naming your migrations with orders to start the filename, to ensure they are processed in the desired order regardless of table name (e.g. `01-create-projecttype.js`, `02-create-project.js`).  This is also important because as you edit / add tables you can keep your old migration steps in tact (e.g. `03-edit-projecttype.js`).

Comment: @slifty thank you - i actually started doing just that! hope v4 of the cli has support for multiple migration folders

Comment: It helped! I was doing a silly mistake where I have defined the different type in both primary and foreign key columns and due to which I have suffered for a couple of mins. Finally worked :)

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2022, you should probably use sequelize-cli to create migration files for you using sequelize migration:generate --name [my_migration_name] as it automatically adds a timestamp before [my_migration_name] therefore saving you the hassle of having to order your migrations manually

Comment: Thank you for this. It helped me fix a related issue (adding back a foreign key constraint). And as it has already been mentioned above, we should use sequelize-cli to create the migration files to ensure proper order.

Answer (score 13):

This is to create migration file for adding a column.

Here I want to add a column **area_id** in **users** table. Run command:

```
sequelize migration:create --name add-area_id-in-users
```

Once it gets executed creates a migration file **timestamp-add-region_id-in-users** in the migrations folder.

In the created migration file paste the below code:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return Promise.all([
          queryInterface.addColumn('users', 'region_id',
            {
              type: Sequelize.UUID,
              references: {
                model: 'regions',
                key: 'id',
              },
              onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
              onDelete: 'SET NULL',
              defaultValue: null, after: 'can_maintain_system'
            }),
        ]);
      },

      down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return Promise.all([
          queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'region_id'),
        ]);
      }
    };
```

Here in the users table I am going to create a column named region_id along with type and relation/foreign key/references. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

So first one goes as the below solution and the second question: you need not explicitly mention `createdAt` and `updatedAt` because they are generated by the Sequelize for you.

The solution is:

```
queryInterface.createTable('Images', {

  //...

}).then(

  return queryInterface.addConstraint('Images', ['postId'], {

    type: 'foreign key',

    name: 'custom_fkey_images',

    references: { //Required field

      table: 'Posts',

      field: 'id'

    },

    onDelete: 'cascade',

    onUpdate: 'cascade'

  })
)
```

Comment: Hi, OP asked two questions and you answered no one. Please edit your answer and add some description to your solution. Make sure that you're answering OP's questions.