# Sequelize fields must be specified through options.field error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

So I created a table and modified it later on to add a foreign key. I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428160/12539780 but it gives me an error that says

"ERROR: Fields must be specified through options.fields"

I am using sequelize ^6.6.5 and my node version is 14.17.6 my code is provided below

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    Promise.all([
      await queryInterface.addColumn('bonus_transactions', 'wallet_id', {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        after: 'order_id'
      }),
      await queryInterface.addConstraint('bonus_transactions', ['wallet_id'], {
        type: 'FOREIGN KEY',
        name: 'FK_bonus_transactions_wallet_id',
        references: {
          table: 'wallets',
          field: 'id'
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      })
    ]),
  down: queryInterface => queryInterface.removeColumn('bonus_transactions', 'wallet_id')
```

could this be because of the sequelize version? I search through the v6 documentation and there doesn't seem to be any implementation that is similar to this.

Comment: Don't use `await` if you use `Promise.all`, simply remove it. And what method out of two is caused this error?

Answer (score 5):

Fields in `addConstaint` should be indicated in `fields` option like this:

```js
queryInterface.addConstraint('bonus_transactions',{
        type: 'FOREIGN KEY',
        name: 'FK_bonus_transactions_wallet_id',
        fields: ['wallet_id'], 
        references: {
          table: 'wallets',
          field: 'id'
        },
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
      })
```